# The Operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Widget' . Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have issues in the following code where am using a simpleanimation flutter package. Issue occurring in this statement `opacity: animation?["opacity"]`. It prompted me to do add null safety and so I did, but then it gave this error **The Operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Widget' . Try defining the operator '[]'**. How to resolve it?
**Code of MovieTween is **

```
final tween = MovieTween();
tween.tween('opacity', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));

tween.tween('translateY', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
curve: Curves.easeOut);
return PlayAnimationBuilder<Movie>(
        delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
        tween: tween, // provide tween
        duration: tween.duration,  // total duration obtained from MovieTween
        builder: (context, value, animation) {
          return Opacity(
              opacity: animation?["opacity"],
            child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]),
                    child: child
                  ),
          );
        },
    );
```

Am adding **code of MovieTween class** below:

```
  /// Animates a property and returns the implicitly created scene.
  /// The scene can be used to add further properties to the scene or to
  /// add further scenes to the movie.
  MovieScene thenTween<T>(
    /// Property to animate
    MovieTweenPropertyType property,

    //// Tween that describes the property animation.
    Animatable<T> tween, {

    /// Duration of the scene
    required Duration duration,

    /// Fine-tune the begin time of the next scene by adding a delay.
    /// The value can also be negative.
    Duration delay = Duration.zero,

    /// Custom curve for this property.
    Curve? curve,
    Curve? sceneCurve,
  }) {
    return thenFor(duration: duration, delay: delay, curve: sceneCurve)
        .tween(property, tween, curve: curve);
  }

  /// Adds an additional scene that begins immediately after this scene.
  MovieScene thenFor({
    /// Duration of the scene
    required Duration duration,

    /// Fine-tune the begin time of the next scene by adding a delay.
    /// The value can also be negative.
    Duration delay = Duration.zero,

    /// Custom curve for this scene.
    Curve? curve,
  }) {
    return parent.scene(
      begin: begin + this.duration + delay,
      duration: duration,
      curve: curve,
    );
  }
}

class _SceneItem {
  final MovieTweenPropertyType property;
  final Animatable tween;
  final Curve? curve;
  final Duration shiftBegin;
  final Duration shiftEnd;

  _SceneItem({
    required this.property,
    required this.tween,
    required this.shiftBegin,
    required this.shiftEnd,
    this.curve,
  });
}

/// A snapshot of properties that are animated by a [MovieTween].
/// This class can obtained by using [MovieTween.transform].
class Movie {
  final Map<MovieTweenPropertyType, dynamic> _map;

  Movie({required Map<MovieTweenPropertyType, dynamic> map}) : _map = map;

  /// Returns the value for a given [property].
  V get<V>(MovieTweenPropertyType property) {
    assert(_map.containsKey(property), 'Property $property was not found.');
    return _map[property] as V;
  }
}

class _AbsoluteSceneItem {
  final MovieTweenPropertyType property;
  final Animatable<dynamic> tween;
  final Curve curve;
  final int begin;
  final int end;

  _AbsoluteSceneItem({
    required this.property,
    required this.tween,
    required this.curve,
    required this.begin,
    required this.end,
  });
}

/// Any [Object] can act as a tween property.
typedef MovieTweenPropertyType = Object;

/// Type-safe tween property that can be used as a `const`.
class MovieTweenProperty<T> {
  MovieTweenProperty();

  /// Returns the current value of this property.
  T from(Movie movie) => movie.get(this);
}
```

Comment: can you include your `MovieTween`

Comment: ok am including it

Comment: try `(animation as Map? )?["opacity"] as double?? 0,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `(animation as Map? )?["opacity"] as double?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter to the builder method is a Widget which would be more appropriate to name it "child".

The value you specify for the opacity maybe should be value.

```
opacity: value
```

Comment: what you mean? can you please elaborate? and highlight that how can I get the output that  this "animation['opacity']" was supposed to do? In previous dart versions, it wasn't an issue, I read the Dart API but couldnt find an alternative, tho there is AnimatedOpacity but being new to Dart, I wasn't able to figure out what it does.

Answer (score 0):

As I've looked through similar issues and solutions, `simple_animations` docs and read a few code, I think I understood what's wrong with your code.

[It seems like](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueWidgetBuilder.html) the third parameter in `builder:` method inside your `PlayAnimationBuilder` is a **Widget** (It's better practice to rename that parameter). And as we all know, we cannot treat widgets as a map. So, `simpleWidget["something"]` won't work.

In order to set your opacity, **the best way** is to use the `value`. You can use the `.get()` method with your `value` to get hold of your desired configuration, or you know, you can just use it as is.

> `MovieTween` animates to `Movie` that offers you a `get()` method to obtain a single animated value.

The value represents the current state of the animation and holds the interpolated values for each property. It might be a good idea to use value as it is.

```dart
return PlayAnimationBuilder<Movie>(
  delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
  tween: tween,
  duration: tween.duration,
  builder: (context, value, widget) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: value, // use 'value' directly as the opacity value, not using get() right now
      child: Transform.translate(
        ...
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Or if you have a custom class that acts as a **type-safe identifier for a tween property**, you can use that as well.

```dart
return PlayAnimationBuilder<Movie>(
  delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
  tween: tween,
  duration: tween.duration,
  builder: (context, value, widget) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: value.get(MovieTweenProperty<double>()), // now we use get() <-
      child: Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(0, value.get(MovieTweenProperty<double>())), // here dont use animate and instead use the value
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Hope this solves your issue. Feel free to provide more information so that we can solve your issue if this one doesn't work for you.